# Why JMeter is unalbe to record .swf flash file requests?

Tags: jmeter

I have tried recording one web application through JMeter and nothing has been given in the field "Urls to exclude". All the requests have been recorded except .swf. But when I tried recording in fiddler .swf got recorded. Could anyond pease  tell me why JMeter is unable to record such requests when fiddler can able to do it??

Comment: JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler doesn't "play" it either - browser does. While Fiddler just sits in the middle and catches all HTTP(S) communications between your browser & target service. It doesn't even "know" & "care" something is "played" somewhere - it just listens to HTTP communications, that's all.

And as soon as you HAVE this particular request recorded in Fiddler, and all other recorded the way you wanted it, right into JMeter elements - what's the problem?

Just add that part manually to your test plan!